# Commutativity of matrices in Isabelle/HOL

Tags: isabelle

I'm trying to prove the following lemma:

```
lemma 
fixes  A B C D :: "((real, 3) vec, 3) vec" 
and v m :: " (real, 3) vec"
assumes "∃ A. m = D ** A ** B *v v"
shows   "∃ A. m = D ** B ** A *v v"
```

but I couldn't do so since `∃ A. D ** A**B *v v = D ** B**A *v v` can be proved straight forward. Probably because of `∃ A`!. Could anyone explain why Isabelle/HOL can't prove this?
Thanks